# Linear search not working; getting an IndexError

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a linear search

```
L = [0, 1, 2]; X= 3;i=0
while (L[i]!= X)and (i < len(L)):
    i = i+1
if i==len(L):
    print('Not here!')
else:
    print(X, 'at position', i)
```

but there is an issue with my while loop and with an `IndexError`.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. Indent the `if` block to match the `while` block 2. Swap the conditionals, `while (i < len(L)) and (L[i]!= X)`

Answer (score 3):

The `and` statement is a [*short-circuit operator*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not), so it only evaluates the argument on the RHS if the argument on the LHS if `True`. In your case, this creates an index error. Swap the order of the conditionals and your code will work perfectly:

```
L = [0, 1, 2]; X= 3;i=0
while (i < len(L)) and (L[i]!= X):
    i = i+1
    if i==len(L):
        print('Not here!')
    else:
        print(X, 'at position', i)
```